# Armstrong number shows wrong output twice and correct at the end (Python)

Tags: python

```
x = int(input("enter your number"))
f = x 
sum_ = 0
while(f>0):
    a =f % 10
    f = int(f//10)
    sum_ =sum_ + (a**3)
    if (x == sum_):
        print("it is armstrong")
    elif (x!= sum_):
        print(x,"is not an armstrong number")
```

When I run this code, I get the following output:

```
enter your number153
153 is not an armstrong number
153 is not an armstrong number
it is armstrong
```

Why does it show incorrectly two times, and the correct output once at the end? How can I fix this?

Comment: Try to  avoid using built-in `sum` as variable name.

Answer (score 1):

As previous post has pointed out, the `if-loop` should be put in outside of the `while` loop to avoid the double print.

Alternatively, you can make this into a function to be used later:

```
def is_armstrong(n: int) -> bool:
    num = str(n)
    powered = len(num)

    return n == sum(int(x)** powered for x in num)


if __name__ == '__main__':
     nums = [153, 371, 456]

     for num in nums:
         print(f' {num} is an armstrong? {is_armstrong(num)} ')

     # or calling by asking user input:
     # x = int(input('Type a number to check: '))
     # print(is_armstrong(x))


# 153  True
# 371  True
# 456  False
```

Answer (score 0):

put the if condition outside the while loop.

```
x=int(input("enter your number"))
f=x 
sum=0
while(f>0):
    a=f%10
    f=int(f//10)
    sum=sum+(a**3)
if (x==sum):
   print("it is armstrong")
elif (x!=sum):
   print(x,"is not an armstrong number")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `if condition` is continuously being checked for each digit in the input number. You'll need to write the `if condition` outside the loop, to have it checked only once.

corrected code:

```
x=int(input("enter your number"))
f=x 
sum=0
while(f>0):
    a=f%10
    f=int(f//10)
    sum=sum+(a**3)
if (x==sum):
    print("it is armstrong")
elif (x!=sum):
    print(x,"is not an armstrong number")
```

Note that your condition was just unindented one level to make it outside your loop.

Answer (score 0):

A functional programming approach.

```
def is_amstrong(n):
    return n == sum(map(int(3).__rpow__, map(int, str(n))))

# test: all amstrong numbers less than 1000
for i in range(9999):
    if is_amstrong(i):
        print(i)
```

Output

```
0   # <- trivial case
1   # <- trivial case
153
370
371
407
```

By adding a check on the input number, such as `n>1`, the trivial cases can be avoided.